# UITableView setContentOffset:animated not correct

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

My code is like this:

```
[tableview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,180) animated];
```

But sometimes, it is not correct,the tableview's y-offset is just 20 or some other value.

I debug the code and find in `UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:`, they just put it to a wrong y-offset value(like 20 or something), not the y-offset value i give to the tableview.

Comment: Post some code, like the place where you call setContentOffset:CGPointMake

Answer (score 0):

I think your contentoffset gets transformed within viewWillAppear, try to put your animation in viewdidload or usenthe following animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuratio:0.3 completion.....{
}];
```

Hope this helps!!